# Relationship between ROS build farm and Jenkins

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are they different CI tools or they work together become a CI works for ROS? I find following passage but not quite understand it:

> The ROS build farm is used to provide the official ROS packages and successfully works with a large number of repositories and packages. Beside building Debian packages it also provide continuous integration builds, GitHub pull request testing as well as documentation generation. Jenkins provides an easy interface to the result of all unit and rostests. It is build around the recommended ROS tools and uses Docker to perform easily repeatable results.
>
> The Python package also provides a command line interface to use each job type in other environments, e.g. on any CI server (e.g. how to run a devel job on Travis) or locally.
> It can be used to deploy a custom build farm to build and release custom, optionally closed-source packages, build for platforms and architectures not provided by the official ROS build farm, and/or customize any part of the process to specific needs.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273364/relationship-between-ros-build-farm-and-jenkins/) by [lt101018](https://answers.ros.org/users/32273/lt101018/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-10-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tl;dr: "the ROS buildfarm" is a specially configured instance of Jenkins. The configuration (of jobs) is generated by Python scripts. Those scripts can also be used without Jenkins (ie: to run the jobs locally, on your own computer).

Jenkins is not a "CI tool", but a generic "open-source automation server".

---

The ROS buildfarm *is* Jenkins. But then specially configured to build ROS packages. The files in `ros_buildfarm` are templates and scripts that use those templates to generate configuration files for a Jenkins instance that transforms it into "a ROS buildfarm".

Note that Jenkins is not a "CI tool", it's (to use their own words): "an open-source automation server". It can be used to setup/implement a Continuous Integration environment, but it could also be configured to download pictures of cats from the internet.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2